# Basic React/redux testing with mocha/chai

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, chai

I'm new to react/redux world, I created the redux todo app using [this code](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html), Now I wanted to write tests for it, I create following spec:

```
import {expect} from 'chai'
import todoApp from '../src/reducers'
import {setVisibilityFilter} from '../src/actions'

describe('reducer', ()=> {
    it('Set correctly visibility filter', ()=>{
        const setVisibilityFilterAction = setVisibilityFilter('SHOW_ALL')
        const initialState={};
        const nextState= todoApp(initialState, setVisibilityFilterAction)
        const expectedState ={
                todos:[],
                visibilityFilter:'SHOW_ALL' 
            }
        expect(nextState).to.equal(expectedState);
    })
})
```

However the assertion went fail and the error is:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (todos, visibilityFilter) } to equal { Object (todos, visibilityFilter) }
      + expected - actual
```

Tried to print the object and they(`expectedState` and `nextState`) both have the same data:

```
{
   todos:[],
   visibilityFilter: "SHOW_ALL"
}
```

why it went fail?

Comment: Hi, a separate  question: how do you manage to test es6 code? Did you run it in node? Are you using babel?

Comment: yes, I'm using babel. you will need a transpiler for es6 (at least for now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`equal()`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal) from Chai's `expect` interface is a strict equality check. It sounds like you want [`eql()`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql) or `.deep.equal()`.

```js
// Equivalent to nextState === expectedState
expect(nextState).to.equal(expectedState);

// Instead:
expect(nextState).to.eql(expectedState);

// Or:
expect(nextState).to.deep.equal(expectedState);
```

Comment: it worked with eql(), however, why the testing from http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html uses equals and works? does it have something to do with immutable.js?

Comment: I don't know, maybe. Those examples with `.equal(List.of(` don't actually look to me like they'd work, but I haven't run it. (In general, lots of code in blogs / tutorials has mistakes.) In any case, the answer to your question is that you can't use just `equal()`.